# Order status logic in PHP

Tags: php

having some issues displaying the correct order status. What I want to achieve is to let the user know if their order is:

No order,
Interested in making an order,
Refunded,
Dispatched,
Payment Received, 
Free of Charge,
Order Placed.

So far I have:

```
if($no_order){
    $status = "No Order";
}
else{
    if($interested){
        $status = "Interested";
    }
    if($refunded){
        $status = "Refunded";
    }
    etc..
}
```

My problem is I start to get issues when I start adding more if's inside the else statement. I have tried elseif but didn't have much luck. Is there an alternate solution to check the order status? instead of using if/else statement? Many thanks!

Comment: use switch cases if you don't want to use if else

Comment: Hi @AghaUmairAhmed, I would try that, but multiple results return true. As in a person can be Interested and a payment has been received for example

Comment: you're setting _one_ status but it sounds like you want to set _many_.  Wouldn't you need to return all the various statuses in an array or something?  A particularly elegant solution would probably require more of an idea about how `$interested`, etc are set before this point.

Comment: use breaks in your case statements.

Comment: The idea is to only set ONE status @DanFarrell. Like for example a user is interested in an order. But a day later there was an issue on so the order was refunded. the status refunded would take priority over interested.

Comment: putting data within the logic of case or if statements gets icky fast.  Better to define your data, and then pass it through a test.  See my solution below.

Comment: If you have a priority, check the highest priority first.

Answer (score 2):

Putting your test conditions in an array is the cleanest way.
This code works for me.  Here, I'm defining an array `$ordered_statuses` which can hold both the name of the variable to check and an object capable of performing the check and providing the appropriate text (if the check succeeds), in the order of precedence as you describe above.  Then I iterate over it and set `$status` to the correect value.

Basically what we're doing here is using polymorphism to allow the behavior of an object ( specifically, `checkValue`) to vary while keeping a consistent interface.  In fact, using a PHP `interface` for the base class would be applicable - but that is an exercise for the reader.

"Variable variable names" are a bit messy - probably there is a better way to do this, depending on the conaining code, but I think this does what you're looking for.

```
<?php
class statusCheck {
    function __construct($text){
        $this->text = $text;
    }
    // this can be overridden to 
    // provide different tests.
    function checkValue( $value ){
        return $value ? $this->text : false;   
    }
}
// here's an example of overriding for a more complicated check
class interestCheck extends statusCheck{
    function checkValue($value){
        // maybe interest has to be high enough?
        if( $value > 5 ) 
            return $this->text;
        else
            return false;
    }
}

$ordered_statuses = Array(
    "no_order" => new statusCheck("No Order"),
    "interested" => new interestCheck("Interested"),
    "refunded" =>  new statusCheck("Refunded" )
);
$interested = 7;
//$refunded = true; // should take precedence
$status = 'None';
foreach( $ordered_statuses as $status_name=>$test){
    $text = $test->checkValue( $$status_name); 
    if( $text != false ) 
        $status = $text;
}
echo "$status\n";
```

Comment: This almost does what I'm looking for @Dan Farrell 
My problem lies in your if statement in the foreach loop. The tests I need to conduct aren't just true/false. I also have to check against dates and SQL results too. Would this mean that i'd need an if else in your foreach loop? How would precedence work then?

Comment: The trick there is to put the check for the status along with the value in `$ordered_statuses`.

Comment: I like that, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Chaned example to show how something like that could be accomplished with Polymorphism.

Answer (score -1):

you can place them in a array like this

```
$ORDER_STATUS = array(
                    0 => "No Order",
                    1 => "Interested",
                    2 => "Refunded",
                    3 => "Payment Received",
                    4 => "Free of Charge",
                    5 => "Order Placed"

                 );
```

now for every status will be index of your array.

**example 1**

if `$status=2`  you can track it directly like `$ORDER_STATUS[$status]` which will be `Refunded`

**example 2**

if `$status=5`  you can track it directly like `$ORDER_STATUS[$status]` which will be `Order Placed`

Comment: I definitely agree that abstracting the logic out from the flow of the program is a brilliant pattern to follow - but this snippet doesn't really help solve the person's question which is finding out what `$status` should be set to in the first place.